# layout div horizontally but work like vertically stacked

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I am trying to create a layout for new dashboard application I am working on.

Requirement is it should layout components horizontally but should behave like stacked vertically ...

Please check codepen I have created https://codepen.io/microchip78/pen/WogPNd

```
check codepen @ https://codepen.io/microchip78/pen/WogPNd
```

When you click on each widget, it will collapsed.

When you click on widget1 & widget2, they collapsed and widget5 should slide up -- which is not happening right now.

When you click on widget1 & widget2, they collapsed and widget5 should slide up -- which is not happening right now.

[image: Collapsing Widget1 & 2]

And when you click on widget3 & widget4, they collapsed and widget6 should slide up but instead, widget5 take its place -- because layout is laying widget horizontally.

[image: Collapsing widget3 & 4]

Any idea how to design this kind of layout ... any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENezzK

```
check codepen @ https://codepen.io/microchip78/pen/WogPNd
```

I have used two panels side by side, which then both have a grid within them.

I am using bootstrap, which you could use, or if you want to continue without you can use a similar structure of using panels.